# F# PowerPack Target Runtime

Tags: f#, assembly-binding-redirect

The pre-built binaries for the F# PowerPack are compiled against the .NET 2.0 runtime. If I have a .NET 4.0 project, is there any advantage to compiling the PowerPack source for the .NET 4 runtime?

Comment: If anyone wants F# PowerPack binaries built against .NET 4.0 with the F# v2 SP1 compiler, I've hosted them [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10282384/FSPowerPackCLR4SP1.7z).

Comment: What would be really nice is an official NuGet package that contains both .NET 2 and .NET 4 binaries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used .NET 2.0 version of F# PowerPack in [F# snippets web site](http://fssnip.net), which is a .NET 4.0 ASP.NET project. The only disadvantage of not using 4.0 version was that I had to add configuration to load 4.0 version of `FSharp.Core.dll` when looking for 2.0 version (which is referenced by the 2.0 version of PowerPack).

I had to add something like the following and then it worked just fine:

```
<configuration>
  <!-- ... -->
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So there is some benefit, but not an enormous one. Still, since F# was released as part of VS 2010, it seems odd that the default binary download of PowerPack would require such workarounds.

Comment: I've just had a problem with an asp.net mvc 3 site using fsharp and fsharp powerpack.  It was failing with Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).  I added a dependantAssembly element as noted above and that sorted it.

Comment: @Kit This was quite some time ago, so I do not know the details anymore :-). I suppose it might be easier to recompile F# PowerPack for .NET 4.0 (using the source code).

Comment: Yeah tried that - same problem.  I might have made a mistake though as I was in a hurry by that time.  I'll probably stick with the redirect for now. :-)

Comment: @Kit. I got exactly that message (ie. "Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, ") publishing an F# ASP.NET MVC application to Azure from Visual Studio 2010. I've been through lots of Azure related fixes, with some difficulty and no success. Tomas's fix in the web.config worked first time!

Answer (score 0):

My app.config for older .NET is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

but power pack installs and works well on VS2010 and .NET4 [fsproj](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54799#786960)