# Disable Searching The GAC

Tags: c#, .net, f#, gac

I'm trying to use the FSharp PowerPack for the ArgParser library, but running into some serious issues on my machine where it seems to be loading the wrong version of FSharp.Core.dll from the GAC that then causes the load of ArgParser to fail.  Ideally I would get the issue with that fixed (since it works on my coworker's computers) but I've tried all sorts of combinations of uninstalling and reinstalling the FSharp binaries from the system to no avail.

As I don't really like the fact that I cannot just drop the DLLs that are *known* to be the correct ones in the executable directory because of the GAC, if there is any way to just disable searching in the GAC I will happily do that.

I know that that solution would be a bit of a hack, but right now I just need to get this to load and work and I'll try anything.

**EDIT**

Some more info. Here's the load output for the project.

```
'PowerPackTest.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINNT\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'PowerPackTest.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Projects\PowerPackTest\PowerPackTest\bin\Debug\PowerPackTest.exe', Symbols loaded.
'PowerPackTest.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINNT\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\FSharp.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\FSharp.Core.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'PowerPackTest.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINNT\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'PowerPackTest.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINNT\assembly\GAC_MSIL\FSharp.PowerPack\2.0.0.0__a19089b1c74d0809\FSharp.PowerPack.dll'
'PowerPackTest.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINNT\assembly\GAC_MSIL\FSharp.Core\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\FSharp.Core.dll'
```

As you can see, it loads FSharp.Core v4 first, but then loads v2 over it at the last second.  This does not happen on my coworker's machines.

Comment: Ok, so your app is CLR4 - how are you loading the FSharp.Core assembly? I'll guess that you're using LoadWithPartialName at runtime?

Comment: Nope: "open Microsoft.FSharp.Text"
I never reference FSharp.Core explicitly. I've never had to. I always thought it was implied, like System.Core.

Comment: Ah, you're using the F# interpreter... I see. Hmmm. And you're saying your colleagues machines' also have v2+v4 installed in GAC?

Comment: No, not using FSI. It's compiled to an exe.  Actually, FSX scripts that are run through FSI work fine.  And yes, they have both versions installed as well... to my knowledge the installer always installs both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pre-built PowerPack binaries are compiled against CLR v2, and they reference FSharp.Core v2 as well. That's probably what's causing this problem. I don't really understand why a .NET 4 version of the PowerPack isn't offered as a download (or in NuGet!) but you can work around this two ways:

You can set up an [assembly binding redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566858/f-powerpack-target-runtime), but I don't know if this would work for `fsi.exe`.

Or you can download the source code to the F# PowerPack and compile your own .NET 4 version. It's pretty easy.

Comment: I thought that CLR v4 was required for F#?? Is it even possible to use it with CLR v2?

Comment: I also don't understand why there is no 4.0 distro of PowerPack. I needed it a few times and ended up building it myself (which is reasonably straightforward).

Comment: Any suggestions for building it as 4.0? It keeps telling me that BigInteger is not defined :(

Comment: I figured it out... System.Numerics apparently used to be part of FSharp.Core, but is now in it's own DLL... Once I added that, BigInteger was found and it built fine.  AND, it works with my project now that it's on v4.0.  Thanks!

Comment: @Adam - what's actually going on is that F# was designed to work with either CLR v2 or CLR v4. Since v2 lacks BigInteger, FSharp.Core v2 includes an implementation, while v4 relies on System.Numerics from CLR v4.

Answer (score 0):

The GAC always wins - this is a security feature. If you have a different version of FSharp.Core, why don't you drop that in the GAC too and either use a redirect binding in your app.config to force loading of the newer version, or rebuild your app (may not be possible) against the new version?

Comment: the GAC shows that I have v2 and v4 of FSharp.Core.  I have tried telling the project to use a specific version, but it always seems to load v2, not matter what I do.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a guess here - I'll bet v4 is for CLR4. You may have to recompile your application against .NET 4. You can't load v4 assemblies into v2 CLR. You may be able to get away with forcing your app to use CLR4 without recompiling by using the supportedRuntimes element in the app.config file. You will then have to add the redirect binding in the config to redirect v2 to v4. Look it up.

Comment: Already there, here's the entry from App.Config
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at a .net 4.0 project where i am using the ArgParser, i am referencing the FSharp.Core and FSharp.Powerpack, as well as in the app.config i have the redirect setup:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```