# Exceptions in F# when running on Azure

Tags: c#, f#, azure, z3

We have a C# web role running in Azure, and the C# project invokes code in an F# dll that we deploy with our app.

When we’re running locally using the local Azure emulator, our F# code is invoked and runs fine. When it’s running in Azure in the cloud, our F# code fails at a certain point with this exception:

> Failed to parse x's function: var(2).Exception:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'FSharp.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'FSharp.Core,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   at Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Lexing.LexBuffer`1.FromArray(char[] s)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Lexing.LexBuffer`1.FromString(String s)    at
>   Marshal.vars@27.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next)
>   WRN: Assembly
>   binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure
>   logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]. .Will use default
>   function.

We have found some posts that suggest it’s because :

> Windows Azure runs applications in partial trust, as part of
>   sandboxing their execution. However, the F# core libraries are
>   currently installed into the GAC, but do not have the
>   AllowPartialTrustedCallers attribute. So when building F# applications
>   to be run in Azure, the F# libraries must be statically linked using
>   --standalone. The provided templates take care of this, but you'll notice the following side-affects: •             Longer than usual
>   compile times •             Large set of references •             A
>   dummy reference to "RDManaged.dll"
>
> http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpazure

To try to get round this, we follow the advice below and put the `–standalone` flag in the Build config of our F# library.

http://www.42spikes.com/post/F-and-Azure.aspx

However, the F# library doesn’t compile with this flag. We get this build error:

> Error      3              A problem occurred writing the binary
>   'obj\Debug\Analyzer.dll': Error in pass2 for type
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Text.StructuredFormat.Joint, error: One of your
>   modules expects the type 'System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable' to
>   be defined within the module being emitted.  You may be missing an
>   input file              FSC         1              1
>   Analyzer

Could this build error be because of the dependencies our F# project has?  It references FSharp.PowerPack.dll and Microsoft.Z3.dll, as well as another C# library in our solution, AnalyzerCommon.dll (which just contains a common interface that both our F# and C# code implement).

It's interesting that the F# code is called and runs fine, it's only until it hits a certain part of the code - a formula parser that uses FSharp.PowerPack.dll.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Sam

Comment: Did you put `FSharp.Core.dll` along with all the dependencies (I don't know where, since I haven't used Azure). It won't be there by default. There are several annoying bugs with F# static-linking (and so also with `standalone` flag). Try to solve this without static-linking.

Comment: You did put '--standalone' rather than '-standalone', didn't you?

Comment: Yes I have, thanks. And see my comment below.. it may around versions of FSharp.Core.dll.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitly reference all required assemblies in your WebRole application, and set the "**Copy Local**" attribute to "**True**". Check out this [mine blog post](http://blogs.staykov.net/2009/12/windows-azure-role-stuck-in.html). The very first thing I mention is the Copy Local.

The reason that part of your code runs and other not, is the JIT compiler. Everything runs fine, untill you hit a code that requires a missing assembly. Once you have **all** required assemblies explicitly added as reference and set "Copy Local" to "True", there shall be not "File not found" exception.

Please follow up if that helped!

**EDIT**

Windows Azure runs in Full Trust by default. Since SDK 1.3 I think. You may change this by right click on your web role in the Cloud project in Visual Studio Solution, choose Properties, navigate "Configuration" and choose "Full trust".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply,

Yes I add both FSharp.Core.dll and FSharp.PowerPack.dll as references to both my ASP.Net Web App (which is the Web Role), and to the F# library that uses them, and set Copy Local to true with both.

The version of FSharp.Core I reference is v4.0.xxxx, and the exception says it can't find v2.0.0.0.

The exception is raised when it hits code that uses FSharp.PowerPack.dll. Could it need v2.0.0.0 of FSharp.Core.dll?

I have tried changing my dependencies to reference v2.0.0.0 and but VisualStudio keeps automatically reverting the references to v4.0.x.x

Comment: @SamB - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566858/f-powerpack-target-runtime/4567327#4567327 regarding how to get the PowerPack to work with the 4.0 version of FSharp.Core.