# Resolving compile-time references to different versions of the same .NET assembly in the same application

Tags: .net, f#

### Using PowerPack in F# application targeting .NET 4.0 causes some pain

`FSharp.PowerPack.dll` is still (*Why? Are they going to give up with it?*) referencing only `FSharp.Core.dll 2.0` which targets .NET 2.0. At the same time `FSharp.Core.dll 4.0` is not compatible with .NET 2.0.

How does it go when the both `FSharp.Core.dll 2.0` and `4.0` are in GAC? It loads `4.0` as it is compatible with current .NET framework and then tells `FSharp.PowerPack.dll` that everything is already loaded. This can be seen in the both Visual Studio debugger, when the application loads and in Reflector when walking through dependencies.

Everything is fine until we need to redistribute software in portable way. When we actually need, we are to copy `FSharp.Core.dll 4.0` (to sound with .NET 4.0) and `FSharp.PowerPack.dll` to the application local codebase. And then it (*suddenly!*) complains that the reference to `FSharp.Core.dll 2.0` [from PowerPack] is not met.

The problem can be easily solved in the brutal way like mentioned in [F# PowerPack Target Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566858/f-powerpack-target-runtime) topic by simply redirecting reference to existing version of FSharp.Core.dll.

### So what is the question?

The question is why everything is OK without any redirects when we refer assemblies installed to GAC. With GAC it seems to be satisfied with the existence of FSharp.Core.dll 2.0 itself and then it just throws it away, using 4.0 version for all purposes. What is the logic behind this?

*Jeffrey Richter's* CLR via C# seems to say nothing about it...

Comment: The CLR version 4 loader is aware of specific .NET 2 core assemblies and automatically rebinds them to the equivalent .NET 4 version.  FSharp.Core just isn't covered by the same mechanism.  The bindingRedirect in the .exe.config file is a simple workaround for it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, it is so, but newertheless, why it does automatically rebind to FSharp.Core v 4.0 when it is in GAC and does not when it is stored locally? The both local and GAC copies are not system assemblies as far as I can see...

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to make a Portable Library version of PowerPack, or if the portable library framework is just too restrictive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you need to know that CLR 4.0 introduces a separate GAC from CLR 2.0. CLR 4.0's GAC sees the old one, but not vice versa.

Now, in the CLR 4.0 GAC there *is* a redirect - the publisher policy file for FSharp.Core that redirects any request to load version 2.0 to 4.0. This contains essentially the same thing as the config file you link to.

In the CLR 2.0 GAC there is no such redirect, obviously because 4.0 is not in that GAC and wouldn't be compatible anyway.

To have a look yourself, either use the fusion log viewer (fuslogvw) when loading FSharp.Core - it should show the redirect taking place.

Also have a look at the pub.config file which in my CLR 4.0 GAC is in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\policy.2.0.FSharp.Core\v4.0_2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a

Comment: Thank you very much for your exhaustive explanation! At last I can see exactly what happens there.

In this scope there is even more puzzling addressed to F# team in MS research: **why** not to redistribute official PowerPack against 4.0? This should not cause a lot of errors at build time because F# is checked very well and it already works ok at runtime...